# Heroku is giving 'Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, heroku, pg

`Gemfile`

```ruby
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.5'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

`Gemfile.lock`

```ruby
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.1.5)
      actionpack (= 5.1.5)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.1.5)
      actionpack (= 5.1.5)
      actionview (= 5.1.5)
      activejob (= 5.1.5)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.1.5)
      actionview (= 5.1.5)
      activesupport (= 5.1.5)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.1.5)
      activesupport (= 5.1.5)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.1.5)
      activesupport (= 5.1.5)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.1.5)
      activesupport (= 5.1.5)
    activerecord (5.1.5)
      activemodel (= 5.1.5)
      activesupport (= 5.1.5)
      arel (~> 8.0)
    activesupport (5.1.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.5.2)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    arel (8.0.0)
    bindex (0.5.0)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (10.0.0)
    capybara (2.18.0)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    childprocess (0.8.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    crass (1.0.3)
    erubi (1.7.1)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.9.23)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (0.9.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.7.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.2.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    method_source (0.9.0)
    mini_mime (1.0.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    nio4r (2.2.0)
    nokogiri (1.8.2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    pg (1.0.0)
    public_suffix (3.0.2)
    puma (3.11.3)
    rack (2.0.4)
    rack-test (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.1.5)
      actioncable (= 5.1.5)
      actionmailer (= 5.1.5)
      actionpack (= 5.1.5)
      actionview (= 5.1.5)
      activejob (= 5.1.5)
      activemodel (= 5.1.5)
      activerecord (= 5.1.5)
      activesupport (= 5.1.5)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.1.5)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (5.1.5)
      actionpack (= 5.1.5)
      activesupport (= 5.1.5)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    rubyzip (1.2.1)
    sass (3.5.5)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    selenium-webdriver (3.10.0)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      rubyzip (~> 1.2)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.13)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.8)
    turbolinks (5.1.0)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.1)
    turbolinks-source (5.1.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.1.6)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    web-console (3.5.1)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.6.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.3)
    xpath (3.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  capybara (~> 2.13)
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  pg
  puma (~> 3.7)
  rails (~> 5.1.5)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  selenium-webdriver
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  sqlite3
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.1
```

Committed my changes and pushed them. Then, I have pushed the master branch to Heroku with `git push heroku` but I'm still getting:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:188:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
```

when I want to restart my dyno at Heroku.

Comment: Do you want to use sqlite or postgres on your heroku app ? (your gemfile specifies `gem 'sqlite3'` in the developement group , and `gem 'pg'` in the production group).

Comment: what does your `database.yml` file look like?

Comment: Your answer is in your question title. As @RockwellRice implies, the problem is in your `database.yml`, where you incorrectly specify your production db adapter (as indicated by the error in your title) as `sqlite3`.

Answer (score 0):

The production block for your database in `database.yml` should look something like this, change out the `xxxx` with your matching values which should already be in the file, they should be in the other blocks (production, test).  The adapter needs to be changed.

```
production:
  adapter:  postgresql <--- This is the important part
  encoding: unicode
  database: xxxxxxx
  username: xxxxxxx
  password: <%= ENV['xxxxxx'] %>
```